# Issue with changing pointer-events: none due to if-statement, nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, count, onclick

## Objective

- I'm looking at the `.length` of each of these positions:
  **`.player--forward`**, **`.player--defenseman`** and **`.player--goalie`** to see how many of these players have the class **`is-selected`**
- A player is selected when a user clicks the `btn--add` button to add that player to their team.
- Once a position reaches the maximum number that can be chosen: two
  forwards **`(pickedF === 2)`** or three defensemen **`(pickedD === 3)`** or
  one goalie **`(pickedG === 1)`**, I'm looking to make it so any players    that have do not have a class `is-selected` unable to be clicked on    with `"pointer-events:none"`

## Update #1

- Right now, it appears to be counting correctly, but it does not change "pointer-events" to none until after `btn-add` is clicked because of the nesting of the if-statements and I think that some parts are in the `btn-add` click function when they don't need to be

## scripts.js

```
function countPlayers(){
    $(".player").click(function(){

        // Select the current player
        var player = $(this);

        // Count number of players of each position that have been clicked
        var pickedF = $(".player--forward.is-selected").length;
        var pickedD = $(".player--defenseman.is-selected").length;
        var pickedG = $(".player--goalie.is-selected").length;

        // Grab the name of the player last clicked
        playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();

        // Literally magic.
        $(".btn--add").unbind("click");

        $(".btn--add").click(function(){

            // Ensures names don't match
            var spanText = $(".player__pick").eq(0).text();

            // Changes the opacity of a picked player to 0.5
            player.addClass("is-selected");

            if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
                if (spanText !== playerName) {
                    $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                    $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedF < 2) {
                        pickedF++;
                    } else if (pickedF === 2) {
                        $(".player--forward").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                        console.log("Locked forwards");
                    } else {
                        $(".player--forward").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                if (spanText !== playerName) {
                    $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                    $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                    // Issue here
                    if (pickedD < 3) {
                        pickedD++;
                    } else if (pickedD === 3) {
                        $(".player--defenseman").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                        console.log("Locked defensemen");
                    } else {
                        $(".player--defenseman").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                if (spanText !== playerName) {
                    $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                    $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                    // Issue here
                    if (pickedD < 1){
                        pickedG++;
                    } else if (pickedG === 1) {
                        $(".player--goalie").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                        console.log("Locked goalie");
                    } else {
                        $(".player--goalie").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
        });

        $(".btn--remove").click(function(){
            player.removeClass("is-selected");

            if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
                $(".player__pick--forward").eq(0).html("Pick a Forward");
                $(".player__pick--forward").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                $(".player__pick--defenseman").eq(0).html("Pick a Defenseman");
                $(".player__pick--defenseman").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                $(".player__pick--goalie").eq(0).html("Pick a Goalie");
                $(".player__pick--goalie").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");
            }

            console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
        });
    });
}
```

## index.html

```
<div class="popup__text">
    <p class="popup__position">tk-position</p>
    <p class="popup__name">tk-name</p>
    <p class="popup__years">tk-years</p>
    <p class="popup__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ad dicta sunt unde, sed quae nihil inventore voluptates nulla voluptate laudantium nesciunt quo, aspernatur deleniti quod harum, nisi error doloribus.</p>
    <div class="popup__stats">
        <p>tk-stats</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn--add">Add to team</button>
        <button class="btn--remove">Remove from team</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="player player--bobplager player--defenseman" data-id="11">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Bob Plager</p>
        <p class="player__position">Defenseman</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="player player--shanahan player--forward" data-id="12">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Brendan Shanahan</p>
        <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="player player--hull player--forward" data-id="13">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Brett Hull</p>
        <p class="player__position ">Forward</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="player player--elliott player--goalie" data-id="14">
    <div class="player__info animated">
        <p class="player__name">Brian Elliott</p>
        <p class="player__position ">Goalie</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the objectives on your question get my attention. I've tried to fix your code without luck, so many lines of code that I feel lost; then I start to write some line of code to hit the goal ... I don't want to share it as answer (unless you think it helps) since it is all new code but check it out https://jsfiddle.net/uu5zzwtd/

Comment: Really interesting approach to the problem, I did end up solving it on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function countPlayers(){
    $(".player").click(function(){

        // Select the current player
        var player = $(this);

        // Count number of players of each position that have been clicked
        var pickedF = $(".player--forward.is-selected").length;
        var pickedD = $(".player--defenseman.is-selected").length;
        var pickedG = $(".player--goalie.is-selected").length;

        // Grab the name of the player last clicked
        playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();

        // Literally magic.
        $(".btn--add").unbind("click");

        $(".btn--add").click(function(){

            // Ensures names don't match
            var spanText = $(".player__pick").eq(0).text();

            // Changes the opacity of a picked player to 0.5
            player.addClass("is-selected");

            if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
                if (spanText !== playerName) {
                    $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                    $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedF < 2) {
                        pickedF++;
                    }

                    if (pickedF === 2) {
                        $(".player--forward").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                        console.log("Locked forwards");
                    } else {
                        $(".player--forward").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                if (spanText !== playerName) {
                    $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                    $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedD < 3) {
                        pickedD++;
                    }

                    if (pickedD === 3) {
                        $(".player--defenseman").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                        console.log("Locked defensemen");
                    } else {
                        $(".player--defenseman").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                if (spanText !== playerName) {
                    $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                    $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                    if (pickedG < 1){
                        pickedG++;
                    }

                    if (pickedG === 1) {
                        $(".player--goalie").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                        console.log("Locked goalie");
                    } else {
                        $(".player--goalie").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
        });

        $(".btn--remove").click(function(){
            player.removeClass("is-selected");

            if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
                $(".player__pick--forward").eq(0).html("Pick a Forward");
                $(".player__pick--forward").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
                $(".player__pick--defenseman").eq(0).html("Pick a Defenseman");
                $(".player__pick--defenseman").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");
            }

            if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
                $(".player__pick--goalie").eq(0).html("Pick a Goalie");
                $(".player__pick--goalie").eq(0).addClass("is-empty");
            }

            console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
        });
    });
```

}